# Swift Mailer won't use updated settings

Tags: symfony, azure, swiftmailer

After following [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/azure-website.html) to deploy my app to Azure, my app is working perfectly fine on most fronts.

However, when I try to send an email, it will never come through. The error log states

```
[2015-10-06 01:25:58] app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host 127.0.0.1 [An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  #10013] [] []
```

So apparently it is still trying to use the parameters.yml settings that the app had generated in the beginning.

I have however edited the parameters.yml file to point to my SendGrid account, but those settings don't seem to be used. I have already restarted the server and cleared the cache multiple times to no avail.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: HOW did you edit your parameters file?  Sounds suspiciously like a deployment problem to me.

Comment: Well, I used Azure's Kudu's Console, so it may actually be the problem?

Comment: Well ... no ... but yes ... with a kinda on the side.  Have you got a GIT repository or something like it in the mix there?

Comment: Yup, I have a local git repository that I use to push changes to the Azure server.

Comment: I have this line though in my .gitignore "/app/config/parameters.yml"

Comment: There's your problem ... either remove that line (not *really* recommended) or find a way to edit your config directly on your Azure instance.

Comment: But I have actually edited the file through Azure. When I open it through the console, I see my updated file :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the cache through `php app/console cache:clear` apparently did not clear the parameters.yml cache.

For something else, I had to manually delete my cache folders through Azure's command line via `rm -rf app/cache/*` and this also solved my parameters.yml issue.